# Query about declaring size in header files

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a structure that contains a pointer to a fixed sized memory.

Say,

```
// Structure of a page
struct Page {
public:
    // Number of slots
    unsigned short numSlots;
    void *data = malloc(PF_PAGE_SIZE);
};
```

I want to put this declaration in a header file. Should I also explicitly put the `malloc` part in it or it should only contain `void *data` and no details about how much memory the pointer points to?

In short should the declaration look like above or resemble the following:

```
// Structure of a page
struct Page {
public:
    // Number of slots
    unsigned short numSlots;
    void *data;
};
```

Comment: Think about it - supposed you include your header in multiple files.  Do you really want to do a "malloc()" each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the first syntax, it will give you a compiler error.
As for the correct approach, the answers differ depending on whether you are using C or C++.

### In C++:

You should only **declare** the structure member in the header file.
You **initialize** it in the **[Member Initialization List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)** in C++ source file.

**Header file:**

```
// Structure of a page
struct Page {
public:
    // Number of slots
    unsigned short numSlots;
    void *data;
};
```

**Source File:**

```
Page::Page():data(malloc(PF_PAGE_SIZE))
{}
```

Notes:

- It is always better to use a smart pointer rather than a raw pointer.
- Also, In C++ one would usually use `new` and not `malloc` but since your pointer is of the type `void`, `malloc` might also be fine depending on the usage.
- The code above just answers your immediate Q, There are still other important things to be considered.You still need to follow the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)** since you have a pointer member with dynamic memory allocation for your structure.

### In C:

In C, there are no Member Initialization lists, so you have to initialize the member after you create an object of the structure.

**Header file:**

```
// Structure of a page
struct Page {
    // Number of slots
    unsigned short numSlots;
    void *data;
};
```

**Source File:**

```
struct Page obj;
obj.data = malloc(PF_PAGE_SIZE);
```

Comment: In the C++ side, you are missing the constructor declaration, and both the declaration and definition of the copy-constructor and destructor. Without that the answer is *broken* (will cause issues, like memory leaks)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: True that. Updated to point OP to the execellent answer which explains it much more in detail.